# Плагин polylang создает избыточные страницы языков - как из удалить из видимости?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, редирект, wordpress-плагины, robots.txt

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным мультиязычным плагином `Polylang`. Недавно обнаружил, что оказывается он помимо самой страницы записей `https://site.com/ru/страница-записей` создал создал дополнительную страницы языка
`https://site.com/ru` с названием Русский. 
Как исключить эту страницу из видимости и в целом из индекса?
В `htaccess` прописываю

```
Redirect 301 /site.com/ru/ https://site.com/
```

но, он почему-то не работает..?

Comment: А основной язык сайта какой? Но в любом случае - см настройки плагина. Ничего дополнительно в роботсе и тем более в хтацессе делать  не нужно

Comment: @SeVlad основной язык сайта - русский. Проблема в том, что она дублирует мою страницу записей: мало того, что плохо для seo, так еще и в случае обрезки ссылки всякими сервисами типа вконтакте - в посте выводится ссылка с тайтлом `Русский Languages`

Comment: Если русский, то `/ru` вообще не должно быть. См настройки. Там есть чекбокс "The front page url contains the language code instead of the page name or page id "

Comment: @SeVlad да, она у меня снята. если включить - не открывает сайт, в частности главную страницу

Comment: Во первых, при таких проблемах чтобы исключить кеш браузера проверяй ответ сервера через сторонние сервисы напр bertal.ru. Во вторых может ещё где-то что-то мешать. Я вот сейчас спец поставил плаг и у меня на дефолтный `/ru` отдаётся 404. Но  никакие доп. редиректы точно не нужны.

Comment: @SeVlad ок. у меня на cloudfare сертификат https заведен. Возможно, что из-за него такая отдача

Comment: Протоколы точно не при чём. Разверни рядом тесотвый сайт, поставь плаг - посмотри.. Делов же на 10 минут.